# JavaScript localStorage not working to save data after page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, shopping-cart

I have a mini check out JavaScript cart where after the user gets their total they enter how much they're paying with then their change is returned. In order to do that I need to store the "total" variable value after the page loads. Which is why I'm using localStorage. However, it's not working. Can someone help me?

```
var itemsSelectedValues = [];
      // variable above is empty array that will ultimately store the items user selected to purchase
      // var total = 0;
      localStorage.setItem("total", 0);
      // variable above is set to 0 that will ultimately represent total of user purchase

      function listOfCheckedItems(catalogToLookFrom) {
        // line above defines function listOfCheckedItems, with parameter catalogToLookFrom being passed in to represent array object "shoppingItems"
        var yourItemsPurchased = $("input:checkbox:checked");
        // line above sets variable yourItemsPurchased to all the checkbox items that were checked
        for (i = 0; i < yourItemsPurchased.length; i++) {
          // line above is a for loop that loops through the entire length of array "yourItemsPurchased"
             itemsSelectedValues.push(yourItemsPurchased[i].value);
             // line above pushes the value of items in array "yourItemsPurchased" into empty array "itemsSelectedValues"
             // this action occurs each time through the loop
        } // line closes for loop
        console.log(itemsSelectedValues);
        for (i = 0; i < itemsSelectedValues.length; i++) {
          // line above loops through array itemsSelectedValues (entire length of array)
          localStorage.getItem("total") = localStorage.getItem("total"); + catalogToLookFrom[itemsSelectedValues[i]];
          // line above sets the variable "total" to itself plus the value of the item name that's in catalogToLookFrom (which represents array object "shoppingItems")
          // this happens each time through the loop
          // so 1st time "total" is set to itself (which is initially 0) plus the value of whatever the 1st item is. Then so on.....
        } // closes for loop
        document.getElementById("yourPurchase").innerHTML = "Your items purchased <strong>" + itemsSelectedValues + "</strong> came to a total of <br/><strong>$" + localStorage.getItem("total"); + "</strong>";
      } // line closes listOfCheckedItems function

      function getOrderTotal() {
        listOfCheckedItems(shoppingItems);
      }

///////// Part not working

  function whatUserPaidWith() {
    var amountUserPaid = $("#amountPaid").val();
    // line above creates variable "amountUserPaid" which is set to the value of element with an id of "#amountPaid"
    var customerChange = amountUserPaid - localStorage.getItem("total");
    document.getElementById("displayUserChange").innerHTML = "You paid <strong>" + amountUserPaid + "</strong> your change due is <strong>" + customerChange + "</strong>";

  }
```

Comment: Is there any errors in the console? Can you also include the exact error that you are getting in the console. I would think that you would need to cast total to a number like: Number(amountUserPaid) - Number(localStorage.getItem("total"))

Comment: Where you have the following line: localStorage.getItem("total") = localStorage.getItem("total"); + catalogToLookFrom[itemsSelectedValues[i]]; I don't think you can store values like that. Can you change it to the following please and try: var newTotal = localStorage.getItem("total") + catalogToLookFrom[itemsSelectedValues[i]];
localStorage.setItem("total", newTotal);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a problem with the following line of your code:

```
localStorage.getItem("total") = localStorage.getItem("total"); + catalogToLookFrom[itemsSelectedValues[i]];
```

I hope my following suggestions help you.

Firstly there shouldn't be a semi colon in the middle of the statement.
Secondly `localStorage.getItem("total")` cannot be used as a variable to store a value (as you are attempting to do). Rather `localStorage.getItem()` is a method which returns a value.

Here is a quote from [the local storage documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)

> The getItem() method of the Storage interface, when passed a key name,
>   will return that key's value or null if the key does not exist.

So my suggestion is that you change the above lines of your code to the following:

```
var newTotal = localStorage.getItem("total") + catalogToLookFrom[itemsSelectedValues[i]];
localStorage.setItem("total", newTotal);
// lines above set the local storage variable "total" to itself plus the value of the item name that's in catalogToLookFrom (which represents array object "shoppingItems")
```

I hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems; for one thing you are not calling `setItem` with the new total. You should do something like this to set the total:

```
function listOfCheckedItems(catalogToLookFrom) {
  var yourItemsPurchased = $("input:checkbox:checked"),
      itemsSelectedValues = [],
      total = 0
  for (i = 0; i < yourItemsPurchased.length; i++) {
      itemsSelectedValues[i] = yourItemsPurchased[i].value
      total += catalogToLookFrom[yourItemsPurchased[i].value];
  }
  localStorage.setItem("total", total)
  document.getElementById("yourPurchase").innerHTML = "Your items purchased <strong>" + itemsSelectedValues.join(',') + "</strong> came to a total of <br/><strong>$" + total + "</strong>";
}
```

Also when you call `getItem`, it will return a string instead of a number. So if you plan to use arithmetic on the value, you must convert it:

```
var customerChange = amountUserPaid - (new Number(localStorage.getItem("total")));
```